# Android: How to determine how many clients are bound to a service?

Tags: android

In an Android service, is there a way to determine how many clients are bound to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no API to find out how many clients are bound to a Service.
If you are implementing your own service, then in your ServiceConnection you can increment/decrement a reference count  to keep track of the number of bound clients.

Following is some psudo code to demonstrate the idea :

```
MyService extends Service {

   ...

   private static int sNumBoundClients = 0;

   public static void clientConnected() {
      sNumBoundClients++;
   }

   public static void clientDisconnected() {
      sNumBoundClients--;
   }

   public static int getNumberOfBoundClients() {
      return sNumBoundClients;
   }
}

MyServiceConnection extends ServiceConnection {

    // Called when the connection with the service is established
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        ...
        MyService.clientConnected();
        Log.d("MyServiceConnection", "Client Connected!   clients = " + MyService.getNumberOfBoundClients());
    }

    // Called when the connection with the service disconnects
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        ...
        MyService.clientDisconnected();
        Log.d("MyServiceConnection", "Client disconnected!   clients = " + MyService.getNumberOfBoundClients());
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 However, this only works if you have a local service running in the same process as your clients. It doesn't work if your service is running in a remote process and it also doesn't work if you offer your service to multiple clients that are not part of your application.

Comment: David is right,  my example will only work for a Local service.

Comment: I haven't had the need to implement a RemoteService yet, so I'm not sure how the RemoteCallback list would be used to make my example work with a RemoteService.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be an easy, standard way to do this. I can think of 2 ways. Here's the simple way:

Add a call to your service's API like `disconnect()`. The client should call `disconnect()` before it calls `unbindService()`. Create a member variable in the service like `private int clientCount` to keep track of the number of bound clients. Track the number of bound clients by incrementing the count in `onBind()` and decrementing it in `disconnect()`.

The complicated way involves implementing a callback interface from your service to the clients and using `RemoteCallbackList` to determine how many clients are actually bound.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of the connected clients by overriding `onBind()` (increase count), `onUnbind()` (decrease count and return `true`) and `onRebind()` (increase count).

Comment: According to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/2IegSgtGxyE/iXP3lBCH5SsJ), `onBind()` is called once for the first request and a cached `IBinder` is returned by the system on subsequent requests without bothering the service. The documentation regarding this issue is incorrect.