# Android Service Running only when UI is active

Tags: android, service, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle, battery-saver

It seems Android in recent version have introduced multiple restrictions on running services in the Background, which of course it good news for battery life of our devices. My goal is to create an app which adheres to this by only running a service as long as the User is interacting with the app (which seems to be what they are aiming for). But it's anything but clear to me how you can implement this properly. My requirements are as follows:

- The Service should be started as soon as any Activity becomes visible to the user.
- The Service should stay **uninterrupted** in the running state while the user is interacting with the app (browsing between activities).
- When the UI (regardless of what activity was active) is sent to the background, the Service should run for 2-3 seconds and then stop itself. The 2-3 seconds are needed for a clean shutdown of the service.
- The service can be started via a Push message when the app is in the background (or closed), in order to handle incoming events at any time. The service then registers to the Remote Server, and checks for updates. If there are updates, a notification is given to the user. Then the service once more shuts back down after 2-3 seconds of inactivity.

To me, it seems a Bound Service is what is intended to be used. But it's not clear to me how my requirements will fit with the Bound Service model. Is there anyone who have any experience with this, who can point me in the right direction?

EDIT: The "Service" in this case is a Local, In-Process service, which is not intended to be accessed externally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This answer presumes a local, "in-process" `Service`, which is no doubt what you intend to use.)

For your use case, you actually use a combination of techniques to keep the `Service` running.

Use the "bound `Service` model" to keep the `Service` around while any one of your `Activities` are visible. It's simple enough; call `bindService()` in `Activity.onStart()`, and `unbindService()` in `Activity.onStop()`. If you're worried about the `Service` being destroyed in the brief moment of transition between two of your `Activities`, don't be; Android is smart enough to wait for the lifecycle changes of different application components to "settle" before it decides a `Service` is unreferenced/unneeded.

You should use the `BIND_AUTO_CREATE` flag for all your `bindService()` calls. Keep in mind that the `Service` isn't created immediately upon calling `bindService()`; it takes a few milliseconds, and you must be careful to return control to the framework, by returning from whatever lifecycle method (e.g., `onStart()`) you are currently in. Only then will you get a call to `onServiceConnected()`.

You'll need to manually keep track of how many `Activities` are bound to your `Service`, in order to determine when to begin your 2-3 second cleanup logic. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11851688/6759241) for a valid approach. Don't worry about the `Service` being destroyed synchronously during your last `unbindService()` call -- just as with `bindService()`, the actual lifecycle state change is "delayed."

Now the question is, how do you keep the `Service` alive for this extra 2-3 seconds, at this point (the point where you've determined the number of open `Activities` has dropped to 0)? Well, you can simply call `startService()`. You can even call it from a method in your `Service` subclass; as long as you have a valid `Context` available, it doesn't really matter. `startService()` indicates to the system that you want to keep the `Service` around, irrespective of how many `Activities` (or other clients) might be bound to it. In this case, the `Service` won't be restarted -- it's already running!

Once your cleanup is complete, you can call `stopService()` or, better yet, `stopSelf()`. That effectively cancels the `startService()` call, and tells the OS, "I'm done". Expect a call to `Service.onDestroy()` shortly thereafter.

Keep in mind that one of your `Activities` might pop up asynchronously, and re-bind to the `Service`, before cleanup completes. It is an edge case, but one that is easily handled. The `Service` will only be destroyed when both these conditions are true: 1.) No clients are binding/bound, and 2.) no un-cancelled calls to `startService()` exist.

Note that on Oreo and later, the system can be quite aggressive about killing apps with background `Services`. According to [this doc](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background), interacting with the user puts you on the whitelist for "several minutes", so I think 2-3 seconds is going to be OK. Similarly, if you're handling a "high-priority FCM message" (which is what I assume you mean by "push" message), you'll be placed on the whitelist, and allowed another few minutes in which to execute the `Service` (this time using the `startService()/stopSelf()` approach).

Comment: This approach works. The main problem was to keep track of the number of bound activities, as I expected the onUnbind() to be called when the number of bindings was 0. However, that does not work, as this is called during Activity transitions. I do find it strange that the Android API does not facilitate this in a simpler way. After all, the restrictions in Oreo seems to enforce this Service behavior, so I find it strange it's so hard to adhere to (and in no way obvious). Anyway, Thank you :-)