# Can a client technically use a services binder after unbinding from the service?

Tags: android, android-service, aidl, android-service-binding, android-binder

**Background:** I have a few services (open for other apps to use) which run in the same process. The RPC is implemented using AIDL and therefore the services have to be open to multiple threads.

This leads me to the question: can a client still use a binder to make RPC calls even after the client unbound from the service. If so then:

**Issue:** I am worried that a client (either intentionally or accidentally) will bind to one of the services, unbind (possibly destroying the service because there are no other clients bound to it), then still use the binder to make remote calls. But, because the service is destroyed (resources have been released) the calls may cause exceptions. While some exceptions are implicitly "passed" back to the client (e.g. NullPointerException and IllegalStateException), most aren't and will propagate all the way back and crash the process, which may contain other alive services.

EDIT: a client can use a binder after unbinding (example code below). Now, what is the best way for a destroyed service to handle/respond to these calls (keeping in mind that the calls happen on a different thread than the thread which call onDestroy)?

```java
public class MyService extends Service {

    private volatile boolean destroyed = false;

    private final IMyServiceInterface.Stub binder = new IMyServiceInterface.Stub() {
        @Override
        public boolean isDestroyed() {
            // even worse, what if... `if (destroyed) { throw new RuntimeException(); }`
            return destroyed;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) { return binder; }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() { destroyed = true; }

}
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener((view) ->
                bindService(new Intent(this, MyService.class), serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE));
    }

    private final ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
            final IMyServiceInterface service = IMyServiceInterface.Stub.asInterface(binder);
            attemptExperiment(service);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            throw new AssertionError("service wasn't supposed to crash...");
        }
    };

    private void attemptExperiment(IMyServiceInterface service) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            Toasts.show(this, "unbinding service and sleeping for 5 seconds...");
            unbindService(serviceConnection);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            }

            final boolean destroyed;

            try {
                destroyed = service.isDestroyed();
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                Toasts.show(this, "service remote exception");
                return;
            }

            Toasts.show(this, "service destroyed: " + destroyed);
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that it is not possible to use a `Binder` after you've called `unbind()`. This should invalidate the connection between the `Binder` and the remote connection. This should be easy to try though, just write a simple program that does exactly what you're worried about: bind, unbind, then use the `Binder` and see what happens.

Comment: @DavidWasser It turns out the answer is yes; it is possible to use a binder after you've called `unbind()`. Do you have any suggestions on how a service can handle clients which have the ability to make calls even if the service is destroyed?

Comment: I'm confused. If the `Service` is destroyed, how can the requests get through? What happens?

Comment: Documentation for `Service.onDestroy()` says **"Upon return, there will be no more calls in to this Service object and it is effectively dead."**

Comment: @DavidWasser It is because binders live independent of the component lifecycles. When the service is destroyed, the binder still hangs around until the process is destroyed. If there are other things running in the process or Android keeps the process around, then the binder remains active. This allows a client to continue to make transactions on the binder and, therefore, the service even after it has been destroyed.

Comment: @DavidWasser The typical way to prevent this is to make the stub in the service a static class (or a class on its own) and use a weak reference to the service, so the service can get garbage collected. The problem with this is that the binder still has the power to create a strong reference to the service (through `weakRefenence.get()`), and the client can continue to make transactions to the binder, preventing the service from ever getting GCd.

Comment: Hmmm. I probably should play with this myself to understand better. But anyway, why are you concerned? If your clients don't play by the rules then they are courting exceptions/crashes/etc. They shouldn't unbind and then continue to use the `Binder`.

Comment: Funny, I just did a bit of searching about how to determine bound clients and stumbled on this question with some of my own comments/answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849427/android-how-to-determine-how-many-clients-are-bound-to-a-service

Comment: @DavidWasser the problem is that the services are allowed to be used by other apps, which means that I don't have control over what the clients do. I'm trying to figure out what is the best paradigm to prevent a service from crashing (and thereby crashing whatever else is in the process) when a client attempts to make calls on a destroyed service.

Comment: I understand, have you tested what happens when a client makes a call on a dead `Service`? If you keep a flag (as you have in your example code) that the `Service` has been destroyed, you can just check that flag in all your methods and ignore any calls on a destroyed `Service`.  That should prevent your `Service` from crashing. OTOH, If your `Service` crashes, Android will just start it up again on the next `bindService()` call, so I'm still not sure what you are trying to prevent here.

Comment: @DavidWasser using a boolean flag introduces a race condition because onDestroy is called from the main thread and the AIDL calls are called from the IBinder transaction thread pool. And you also can't block in the onDestroy until all calls are finished because then your risk ANR (especially if i/o is involved). And if an exception is raised, I'm not worried about the dead service, I'm worried about it crashing the other *alive* components running in the process.

Comment: You can have your `Service` run in its own process so that a `Service` crash doesn't bother anything else. regarding the race condition you could synchronize on some monitor object to ensure that you don't do anything bad. This shouldn't cause ANR because the calls via AIDL, even if made on worker threads, should not run for long. If they do, you should fix your architecture to provide asynchronous methods with appropriate callbacks. I still think the window of opportunity for bad stuff is tiny. But you need to decide if the effort is justified.